# how can I make a countdown timer perform an action when it runs out?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, timer

this is my very first question here and may not meet some standards, for that i apologize in advance.
I have a site developed in laravel 5 where the users register and are expected to make take an action within a specific period after registration. I have included a countdown timer for that purpose (the time code is shown below). Now I need to automatically remove a user record from the database when the time runs out. Please how can I do that?
the timer code is:

```
<div class="getting-started"></div>
   <?php 
   $time = strtotime($user['updated_at'].'+24 hours');
   $countdown = strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',$time);
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(".getting-started")
   .countdown("{{$countdown}}", function(event) {
   $(this).text(
   event.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
   );
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to store ex. `time_registered`(timestamp) when user is registered. When the user calls this action, check the difference between the time.

Comment: just put the registration date time in the database and created a column for isactive on registration set the value to 0 if they take action set it to 1 (like true or false) then simply if over 24 hours and 0 delete

Answer (score -1):

If you want something to happen on the server, then you should maintain the timer on the server side, not the client side. Otherwise, the user can simply change the timer or otherwise block the action that the expiration is meant to trigger. I would store a timestamp with the user record, noting when it was created. Then write a script to loop over all records that are older than your threshold and perform the desired action on them. Then run this script via a cron that fires at a regular interval.

Comment: This seems to make sense to me but I'm not quite familiar with using cron. Could you give a sample of such scripts please?